# need pandas DataFrame.resample() to honor sub-period series start datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the pandas DataFrame.resample() function to downsample 1 minute-frequency time series data to 15min-frequency.  The original data consists of multiple time series aligned to the same minute-frequency where each series is a list of tuples, each tuple is defined to be `(<offset from start time>, <value>)`.  I'm converting this to `(<datetime>, <value>)` prior to populating a DataFrame.  Here is a sample time series

```
start = datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 6, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
min_ts = dict((start + timedelta(seconds=60) * t, random.randint(0,3)) for t in range(1, 30))

 min_ts = 
 {datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 7, tzinfo=<UTC>): 2,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 8, tzinfo=<UTC>): 1,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 9, tzinfo=<UTC>): 0,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 10, tzinfo=<UTC>): 3,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 11, tzinfo=<UTC>): 1,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 12, tzinfo=<UTC>): 0,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 13, tzinfo=<UTC>): 1,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 14, tzinfo=<UTC>): 0,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 15, tzinfo=<UTC>): 3,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 16, tzinfo=<UTC>): 3,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 17, tzinfo=<UTC>): 3,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 18, tzinfo=<UTC>): 1,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 19, tzinfo=<UTC>): 3,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 20, tzinfo=<UTC>): 0,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 21, tzinfo=<UTC>): 2,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 22, tzinfo=<UTC>): 1,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 23, tzinfo=<UTC>): 0,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 24, tzinfo=<UTC>): 3,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 25, tzinfo=<UTC>): 1,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 26, tzinfo=<UTC>): 1,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 27, tzinfo=<UTC>): 2,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 28, tzinfo=<UTC>): 0,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 29, tzinfo=<UTC>): 3,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>): 2,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 31, tzinfo=<UTC>): 3,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 32, tzinfo=<UTC>): 0,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 33, tzinfo=<UTC>): 3,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 34, tzinfo=<UTC>): 2,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 35, tzinfo=<UTC>): 0}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I load this into a DataFrame and run resample with a 15min frequency, summing the values in-between, the DateTimeIndex labels are coerced to intra-hour 15 minute intervals (i.e. 0, 15, 30, 45) but what I want is to retain the original time series DateTimeIndex (i.e. starting from `datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 24, 1, 7, tzinfo=<UTC>)`).  I've tried using the resample `loffset` config argument which does affect the preferred behavior on the DateTimeIndex but the summed values aren't changed accordingly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': min_ts})
df.resample('15min', how='sum', label='right')

df = 
DateTimeIndex                  values
--------------------------------------
2014-02-24 01:15:00+00:00    11
2014-02-24 01:30:00+00:00    31
2014-02-24 01:45:00+00:00    11
```

What I want the result to look like is

```
df = 
DateTimeIndex                  values
--------------------------------------
2014-02-24 01:07:00+00:00    23
2014-02-24 01:22:00+00:00    21
```

(Updated to more clearly reflect desired result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `base`, `loffset` and/or switching the label to `left` (this uses a different random seed that you).

```
In [17]: df.resample('15min', how='sum', label='right')
Out[17]: 
                           values
2014-02-24 01:15:00+00:00      10
2014-02-24 01:30:00+00:00      17
2014-02-24 01:45:00+00:00       7

[3 rows x 1 columns]

In [18]: df.resample('15min', how='sum', label='right',base=7)
Out[18]: 
                           values
2014-02-24 01:22:00+00:00      16
2014-02-24 01:37:00+00:00      18

[2 rows x 1 columns]

In [19]: df.resample('15min', how='sum', label='left',base=7)
Out[19]: 
                           values
2014-02-24 01:07:00+00:00      16
2014-02-24 01:22:00+00:00      18

[2 rows x 1 columns]

In [21]: df.resample('15min', how='sum', label='right',loffset='7T')
Out[21]: 
                           values
2014-02-24 01:22:00+00:00      10
2014-02-24 01:37:00+00:00      17
2014-02-24 01:52:00+00:00       7

[3 rows x 1 columns]

In [22]: df.resample('15min', how='sum', label='left',loffset='7T')
Out[22]: 
                           values
2014-02-24 01:07:00+00:00      10
2014-02-24 01:22:00+00:00      17
2014-02-24 01:37:00+00:00       7

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: FYI. If you would like to expand http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling with some more examples / explanation when/how to use ``base`` / ``loffset`` would be much appreciated....pls submit a pull-request!